# How to know ext-csd information of sd-card?

Tags: linux, sd-card, mmc3

I have Googled a lot before posting the question here, but I did not found any firm answer or reason.

I want to know/read ext csd register information of a SD-Card. I know that mmc-utils is capable of showing that information in extcsd. But the mmc-utils does not seems to be working for sd-card to get extcsd information.
I tried,

`mmc extcsd read /dev/mmcblk1`

result shows;

```
ioctl: Connection timed out

Could not read EXT_CSD from /dev/mmcblk1
```

Can anyone suggest any work-around to work mmc-utils for sd-cards?

Or Does anyone can refer to such linux tool to monitor sd-card information?

Or any health-monitor utility to serve my purpose?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SD-cards do not have the EXT_CSD register, only eMMCs does.